# Loop through a list of integers - only returning 1 number

Tags: c#, .net

Trying to simply loop through a list of ints, and printing each number via returnNumbers() however it only loops through the list one, returning the first element. Can anyone detect the minor mistake I'm making?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListHolder List = new ListHolder();
        List.addNumber(6);
        List.addNumber(3);
        List.addNumber(2);
        List.returnNumbers();
    }
}

class ListHolder
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    public void addNumber(int val)
    {
        numbers.Add(val);
    }

    public void returnNumbers()
    {
        foreach (int n in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `Console.ReadLine()` in the loop?

Comment: Otherwise the console application instantly exits, it gives me an opportunity to view the output

Comment: You realize you have to press Enter for every number then, right?  Try moving the `ReadLine()` statement to `Main()` after `List.returnNumbers();`

Comment: Move Console.ReadLine() to outside the loop

Comment: Seems like the debugger at your fingertips could have helped you work this one out

Comment: Just run the program with Ctrl+F5 to stop it from closing the window when it completes.

Comment: Please don't use class names for variable names like `List`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `Console.Readline()` out of your loop.
It's only displaying once because the program is waiting for your input.

The way you've written it, you'd have to input something (let's say just hitting the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key) to see each output.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListHolder List = new ListHolder();
        List.addNumber(6);
        List.addNumber(3);
        List.addNumber(2);
        List.returnNumbers();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class ListHolder
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    public void addNumber(int val)
    {
        numbers.Add(val);
    }

    public void returnNumbers()
    {
        foreach (int n in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```